# Finding symmetric difference between two arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In this assignment from freecodecamp, I was given the following mdn resources:

**1. slice()**

**2. filter()**

**3. indexOf()**

**4. concat()**

While yes, I could do this using for loop and other methods, I stuck to what was given to me to figure out the problem. Wondering if I could have done something better/efficient with my code using the resources above.

```js
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];

  var concatArr = arr1.concat(arr2);

  return newArr = concatArr.filter(function(x) {

    if (arr1.indexOf(x) == -1 || arr2.indexOf(x) == -1) {
      return x;
    }
  });
}

console.log(diffArray([1, 2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Replace the if statement with `return arr1.indexOf(x) == -1 || arr2.indexOf(x) == -1;`. Since `x` might be `0`, and it's a falsy value, you'll end up filtering all zeroes as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `newArr` local variable is unnecessary to declare and initialize,
and this is a confusing statement:

> ```
> return newArr = concatArr.filter(...);
> ```

Eliminate the `newArr` variable, you don't need it.
And avoid assigning to values in a return statement.

---

`concatArr` is a waste: it stores the content of both input arrays,
only to filter out elements later.

The filtering logic is also inefficient: for each value in the concatenated array,
it checks if the value is present in both input arrays. But every value is present in at least one of the arrays, so one of the checks is evaluated unnecessarily.

It would be better to reorganize the operations:

- Apply filter on the first array
- Apply filter on the second array
- Concatenate the results of the filters

For example:

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  const diff = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(x => arr2.indexOf(x) === -1);
  return diff(arr1, arr2).concat(diff(arr2, arr1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code breaks when one of the arrays contains a `0` element.

Comment: how would i solve that?

Comment: Sorry, Code Review is not a debugging service.

Comment: Go to www.stackoverflow.com if you want to ask a question on programming. This site is for code review. @user2763557